# Email validation is not working in ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the error after for an invalid email address but validation does not throw an error. I saw several questions/answer but none was able to point out how to get it work. I am using ASP.NET MVC running on .NET 4.8.

In this code, the `Required` field validation is working but not the email validation.

```
[Display(Name = "E-mail")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Email address")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Html.EditorFor` on your `View` instead of  `Html.TextBoxFor` ?

Comment: I tried after seeing your suggestion and it didn't work.